# Unable to authenticate with CAS

Tags: cas, phpcas

I have implemented a SSO service and, after a lot of days, I have got it. But now I have a problem, the CAS service (SSO) works if you are in the local network and in another network which is located in the same place, but if I connect from external network I'm not able to connect. I can access to service but in one step it fails with an error: connection refused.

I use phpCAS in order to authenticate to the service and the log is this:

> 3CEF .=> phpCAS::forceAuthentication() [portal.php:16]
>
> 3CEF .|    => CAS_Client::forceAuthentication() [CAS.php:1098]
>
> 3CEF .|    |    => CAS_Client::isAuthenticated() [Client.php:1280]
>
> 3CEF .|    |    |    => CAS_Client::_wasPreviouslyAuthenticated() [Client.php:1393]
>
> 3CEF .|    |    |    |    no user found [Client.php:1635]
>
> 3CEF .|    |    |    <= false
>
> 3CEF .|    |    |    CAS 2.0 ticket `ST-7-6cgDalH6VPKQ5vE6SyCB-cas' is present [Client.php:1447]
>
> 3CEF .|    |    |    => CAS_Client::validateCAS20('', NULL, NULL, false) [Client.php:1450]
>
> 3CEF .|    |    |    |     [Client.php:3169]
>
> 3CEF .|    |    |    |    => CAS_Client::getServerServiceValidateURL() [Client.php:3176]
>
> 3CEF .|    |    |    |    |    => CAS_Client::getURL() [Client.php:453]
>
> 3CEF .|    |    |    |    |    |    Final URI: https://www.XX.com/portal.php [Client.php:3548]
>
> 3CEF .|    |    |    |    |    <= 'https://www.XX.com/portal.php'
>
> 3CEF .|    |    |    |    <= 'https://XX.com:8442/cas/serviceValidate?service=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.XX.com%2Fportal.php'
>
> 3CEF .|    |    |    |    => CAS_Client::_readURL('https://XX.com:8442/cas/serviceValidate?service=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.XX.com%2Fportal.php&ticket=ST-7-6cgDalH6VPKQ5vE6SyCB-cas', NULL, NULL, NULL) [Client.php:3191]
>
> 3CEF .|    |    |    |    |    => CAS_Request_CurlRequest::sendRequest() [AbstractRequest.php:242]
>
> 3CEF .|    |    |    |    |    |    curl_exec() failed [CurlRequest.php:77]
>
> 3CEF .|    |    |    |    |    <= false
>
> 3CEF .|    |    |    |    <= false
>
> 3CEF .|    |    |    |    could not open URL 'https://XX.com:8442/cas/serviceValidate?service=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.XX.com%2Fportal.php&ticket=ST-7-6cgDalH6VPKQ5vE6SyCB-cas' to validate (**CURL error #7: Failed to connect to XX.com port 8442: Connection refused**) [Client.php:3194]
>
> 3CEF .|    |    |    |    => CAS_AuthenticationException::__construct(CAS_Client, 'Ticket not validated', 'https://XX.com:8442/cas/serviceValidate?service=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.XX.com%2Fportal.php&ticket=ST-7-6cgDalH6VPKQ5vE6SyCB-cas', true) [Client.php:3198]
>
> 3CEF .|    |    |    |    |    => CAS_Client::getURL() [AuthenticationException.php:77]
>
> 3CEF .|    |    |    |    |    <= 'https://www.XX.com/portal.php'
>
> 3CEF .|    |    |    |    |    CAS URL: https://XX.com:8442/cas/serviceValidate?service=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.XX.com%2Fportal.php&ticket=ST-7-6cgDalH6VPKQ5vE6SyCB-cas [AuthenticationException.php:80]
>
> 3CEF .|    |    |    |    |    Authentication failure: Ticket not validated [AuthenticationException.php:81]
>
> 3CEF .|    |    |    |    |    Reason: no response from the CAS server [AuthenticationException.php:83]
>
> 3CEF .|    |    |    |    |    exit()
>
> 3CEF .|    |    |    |    |    -
>
> 3CEF .|    |    |    |    -
>
> 3CEF .|    |    |    -
>
> 3CEF .|    |    -
>
> 3CEF .|    -

As I said, it works in a local and in a "semi-local" network, but I can't authenticate from external network.

I have the port 8442 open and, for some reason, from external network port 8442 is closed. I know that this is the problem but I don't know how to do to put this port listening the application. In fact, CAS service is located in a server and WebService (login, portal...) is located into another server. I have been configuring firewall but probably I'm doing something bad but I don't know what can be because in local it is working perfectly.

If I enter the URL of validateService with service and ticket (https://XX.com:8442/cas/serviceValidate?service=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.XX.com%2Fportal.php&ticket=ST-7-6cgDalH6VPKQ5vE6SyCB-cas) on browser I get the username correctly, so I don't know why in the transaction of phpCAS is not working.

I hope you can help me, thanks for your answers!

Comment: You are getting connection refused. That is clearly a firewall issue. If you have deployed your CAS application on a server, make sure that server is on the proper secure firewall zone that can be accessed externally. I think, a network security person in your organization should be able to help you with this.

Comment: I could resolve it. I did changes on phpCAS source code in order to get correct URL, because as you said, some URL were not accessible from some network.
Now it's working. By the way, thanks for your comment :)

Comment: Glad it helped. I posted that as an answer to help others in future if they end up with the same problem. Please accept the answer if think it was apt for your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting connection refused. That is clearly a firewall issue. If you have deployed your CAS application on a server, make sure that server is on the proper secure firewall zone that can be accessed externally. A network security person in your organization should be able to help you with this.